# Automatically setup jenkins users with CLI

Tags: deployment, automation, jenkins, user-management

I did not find any reference to user related commands for the jenkins-cli tool.

I need this to automate deployment.

Any comeback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you don't want to use Jenkins' internal user database at all.  There are a host of "Authentication and User Management" plugins.

If you like MySQL, there is a MySQL authenticator (it reads a table of users and passwords), and your "adduser" command could do an insert on that table.

If you like flat files, there is a "Script Security Realm", where you can authenticate with an arbitrary script.  Write a file with user and password combos in your favorite format, write an "adduser" script that writes to it, and write an auth script that reads the file and determines whether to authenticate the user.

You can also hook up to an LDAP server, Active Directory, Atlassian Crowd, Unix user accounts (pw_auth), or whatever authentication your application server uses (if it's running off of a Tomcat server, for instance, you can tell Jenkins to let Tomcat authenticate users, and set up Tomcat to do it however you want.

Answer (score 6):

To use jenkins internal database simply use the following command.

```
echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("user1", "password123")' | \
   java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ groovy =
```

This will create user=user1 with password=password123

---

If you have any existing user and have restricted anonymous access to your jenkins, you can specify the username and password with

--username "user_name" and --password "password"

Comment: I can't make it work with --username and --password.
Can you leave some example?

Comment: echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("user1", "password123")' | java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://localhost:8080/" -noKeyAuth groovy = --username admin --password xxx

Comment: just for the record, for me this didnt work with jenkins ver. 2.138.2.
instead for me worked:
`echo 'jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("newuser", "newpassword")' | sudo java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://localhost:8080" -auth adminuser:adminpassword -noKeyAuth groovy =`

Answer (score 3):

If you specify in more detail what you are trying to do people here may help you better. That said, here are some pointers:

All CLI commands are available via `http://[jenkins-server]/cli`. What's not found there is not available via CLI. You can specify user name / password via `--username` and `--password` (or `--password-file`) options in CLI commands.

Another option for Jenkins automation is to use [Python JenkinsAPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi).

You can also use tools like *wget* and *curl* to perform certain actions (such as [starting a build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)). There you may use user-specific tokens instead of username/password.

[Here's another link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients) that can be helpful.